# How to start emacs server in background on startup Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I want an emacs server to be started automatically when I power-up my computer running Windows. Also, I want this server to be a process in the background, not a window. Is it possible, and if so how?

I have added lines below to my `init.el` and I thought when I add them and run a `emacsclientw.exe`, a server should be created if not already existing, and then run the client. But when I try to open `emacsclientw.exe` an error pops up stating that `No socket or alternate editor. Please use: --server-file (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE) --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)`.

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (cond
   ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (setq server-auth-dir "~\\.emacs.d\\server\\"))
   ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
    (setq server-auth-dir "~/.emacs.d/server/")))
  (setq server-name "emacs-server-file")
  (server-start))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a task in Windows via Task Scheduler.

When creating a task, in the field "action", you can specify "start a program", the path to the executable you want to run and the args. So do this :

1. Search for task scheduler in windows search bar.
2. Create a task via the right side button "create a task"
3. Specify "start a program", the path to the executable `runemacs.exe`, for me it's "C:\Program Files\Emacs\emacs-28.2\bin\runemacs.exe", and the arg `--deamon`
4. Specify that you want this task to run at start-up or when opening a session

And that should do it.